# Returns the number of unique values in data studio when date matters

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I have my dataset in Google spreadsheet and I wish to know the unique number of customers in a specific date range:

Let's say this is my data set

```
Customer                  Date
A                         22/07/2017
B                         24/07/2017
A                         23/07/2017
```

I use this formula `COUNT_DISTINCT(Customer)` however because row 3 have different date from row 1 the output is 3 (however, I wish to have 2 as my output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know the number of unique values in column A regardless of the date then would this formula work:

`=COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A)`

Or is you want to combine this with a specific date range then:

`=COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,B2:B>=datefrom,B2:B<=dateto))`

In this formula, datefrom and dateto can be either a value or a cell reference